# Fitting point to plane??

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, 3d

As explained [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html), given a plane:

> *ax + by + cz + d* = 0

and a point **x<sub>0</sub>**=( *x<sub>0</sub>* , *y<sub>0</sub>*, *z<sub>0</sub>* ), the normal vector to the plane is given by:

> **v** = [ *a* ; *b* ; *c* ]

and a vector from the plane to the point is given by:

> **w** = -[ *x-x<sub>0</sub>* ; *y-y<sub>0</sub>* ; *z-z<sub>0</sub>*
>   ]

Projecting **w** onto **v** gives the (shortest) distance ***D*** from the point to the plane as:

> ***D*** = ( *ax<sub>0</sub> + by<sub>0</sub> + cz<sub>0</sub> + d* )
>   / ( *sqrt( a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> + c<sup>2</sup> )* )

The question is simple: how to fit the point **x<sub>0</sub>** to the plane, i.e. how to move it to ( *x* , *y*, *z* ) position, which is the closest point lying on the plane to **x<sub>0</sub>**.

Comment: You can construct the equation of the line from the normal vector (use them as direction cosines after mormalization) and the point outside the plane; find the intersection of that line with your plane.

Comment: I think I've found the solution, thanks!

Comment: If so, please consider writing an answer to your question, so that it can be a reference for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the line is:

> *x* = *x<sub>0</sub>* + *at*
>
> *y* = *y<sub>0</sub>* + *bt*
>
> *z* = *z<sub>0</sub>* + *ct*

And the intersection of the line with the plane is given by:

> *a*(*x<sub>0</sub>* + *at*) + *b*(*y<sub>0</sub>* + *bt*) + *c*(*z<sub>0</sub>* + *ct*) + d = 0

Just need to find *t* and substitute it in the line equation to find the point ( x , y, z ).

Comment: Nicely done. A masochist would have tried to determine two planes passing through the line and then use Gaussian elimination. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to solve this is already in your question. The shortest distance to the plane is, as you say, in a direction parallel to the normal, so if you move that distance along that direction toward the plane, you end up at the nearest point on the plane to the given one. I.e., $$\mathbf x = \mathbf x_0-D{\mathbf v\over\|\mathbf v\|} = \mathbf x_0 - {\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf x_0+d\over\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf v}\mathbf v.$$ Note that $D$ is signed, which we want because that encodes which side of the plane $\mathbf x_0$ is on relative to $\mathbf v$. I’ll leave it to you to verify that $\mathbf x$ is indeed on the given plane.

Comment: Good explanation. **x** is on the plane, and **_D_** is signed, being positive if the point is on the same side of the plane as the normal vector, and negative if it is on the opposite side. That is important to take into account when moving the point to ( _x_ , _y_, _z_ )